# HttpClient throws timeout but Postman works as expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015, dotnet-httpclient

I'm dealing with this strange issue. I'm trying to make a http post to a server through a vpn. I'm using OpenVPN to connect to it.

If I make the post requests through postman it works flawlessly. If I make it through visual studio nothing happens and a timeout is thrown afterwards.

I disconnected the ethernet and connected a wifi usb board and visual studio started working for a while. Then it suddenly stopped sending the request. I can't recall anything I did that made the request to stop working.

I'm monitoring everything through wireshark. The postman request appears, the visual studio doesn't.

```
public class CustomObject
    { 
   /* lots of properties */
    public async void MakeRequest()
        {
            try
            {
               var response = await RequesterDespacho.MakePost("CreateTicket/", this);
                switch (response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                        return;
                    case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                        Logger.Info("[DESPACHO] Forbidden");
                        break;
                    case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                        Logger.Info("[DESPACHO] Bad Request: ");
                        break;
                    case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                        Logger.Info("[DESPACHO] Error 500");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //TaskCanceledException = timeout
            {
                Logger.Error(ex.ToString);
            }

        }
}

public static class RequesterDespacho
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client;

    static RequesterDespacho()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.2.4.29:1234");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-auth_token", "token1");
    }
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakePost(string dir, object data)
    {
        return await client.PostAsJsonAsync(dir, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: How long does the request take in postman? Maybe longer than HttpClient default timeout?

Comment: no, no more than 2 seconds, visual studio has 100 sec timeout

Comment: I disabled all connections and re-enabled the wifi and now it works! its just very random...